# SQL Server stored procedure export to Excel workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

How can I export to an Excel workbook from a stored procedure to multiple sheets with few sql statements?

I am currently using the following statement:

```
EXEC proc_generate__excel 'db', 'temp',@filename, @SeqNo, @ext, @sqlorder
```

It will create three Excel workbooks, if there are three sql statement.

How can I export data from three sql statement to **three sheets in one Excel workbook**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create an empty Excel file with the sheets in it you need (my example sales.xls with sheets "sheet1","sheet2")
2. Copy empty file to desired location/name
3. Using your select statement to get the desired information for sheet1; insert the data into the excel file:

   ```
   insert into OPENROWSET(
      'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
      'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\export\sales.xls;;HDR=YES', 
      'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
   select * from sales_part1
   ```
4. Using your select statement to get the desired information for sheet2; insert the data into the excel file:

   ```
   insert into OPENROWSET(
       'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
       'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\export\sales.xls;;HDR=YES', 
       'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]')
   select * from sales_part2
   ```

Check these links for reference:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic487837-19-1.aspx
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic660148-338-1.aspx
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3331881_1

Some SO threads:
[SQL Server export to Excel with OPENROWSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909933/sqlserver-to-excel-export-with-openrowset)
[error on sql script with 'openrowset'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437172/error-on-sql-script-with-openrowset)

Comment: Not working in 64bit Windows 7. It is not flexible, because it depends on the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.

Comment: check your installed ms office version..and use their connection string (oledb version) as per the office connectivity redistributable

Comment: check these [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) and excel related info.. it is not to tell you about connection string..  just to tell you use office compatible specification in your openrowset ... hope this help you as per you platform version.